# JS: when add html dynamically, they go without the event

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I add html dynamically, the new elements go without reference at event. For example:

```
function create() {
    addButton();
}
function addButton() {
    let button = `<button type='button' class='btn btn-secondary'>Button</button>`;
    $('body').append(button);
}

$('button').on('click', create);

create();
create();
create();
```

This script results in 3 buttons. That when clicked adds a new button. But this new buttons when clicked nothing happens, because they have not referenced the "create" function when clicked.

Why?

[image]

The buttons that are created when the script runs, have "event". Those that are dynamically created do not.

Comment: You need to use a delegate event handler for dynamic content. See the duplicate question for more details. Also, your `create()` function is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: KAPOW and it was closed

Comment: @mplungjan I have a very over developed 'event binding dupe' trigger finger ;)

Comment: Me too :)))))))

Comment: Look at the picture. Dynamic buttons have no event.